# Sleep Secondary Display Mac

Tags: macos, sleep, external-display

I am trying to only have secondary monitors turn off. I have seen this code:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

/* Returns 0 on success and 1 on failure. */
int display_sleep(void)
{
    io_registry_entry_t reg = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/IOResources/IODisplayWrangler");
    if (reg) {
                IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(reg, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"), kCFBooleanTrue);
                IOObjectRelease(reg);
        } else {
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

However, it appears as through the code will put all monitors asleep.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to put only the secondary monitors to sleep?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a rather rude thing to do. Won't your users want to use their displays for something else?

Comment: It is to save power and heat. When a display is on, it can get very hot, and when not in use, this code will be used to power down the display and only keep the main display active.